# Mysql Between Query with two columns

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `location_details` WHERE 24.776 BETWEEN startLatitude And endLatitude And 67.077 BETWEEN startLongitude And endLongitude
```

I want to get the row which is between these column i have start and longitude,
start and end latitude user provide only on latitude and longitude i want to find out which area those langitude and altitude lies

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: i have four columns startLatitude endLatitude startLongitude endLongituden user provide only one longitude and latitude i want to find out which area those langitude and altitude lies

Comment: What is wrong with the query you've presented?

Comment: its not providing any output it runs fine if i use only latitude but when i am using longitide it shows no output

Comment: Perhaps you should share sample data where your query isn't working.  Sounds like your data though -- make sure results should show up for those ranges.  When working with latitude and longitude, also make sure you pay attention to positive and negative values.

Comment: 1  24.773  67.043  24.8099  67.076  defence

Comment: Um, and how is `67.077` less than `67.076`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT * FROM `location_details` WHERE (24.776>=startLatitude And 24.776<=endLatitude) And (67.077>= startLongitude And 67.077<=endLongitude)
```